# Add .pcap ending to all files created with tcpdump

Tags: linux, formatting, filenames, tcpdump

I'm using tcpdump for a rotating network traffic capture, and Moloch as a nice viewer for the data. The problem is that tcpdump appends a number to the *end* of the filename, while Moloch only uses files that end in .pcap.

Is there a way to set up tcpdump to create filenames ending in .pcap?

Using a date format string doesn't work because I need the filenames to repeat (after every 20 files or so).

`sudo tcpdump -i eth0 -s 0 -W 4 -G 15 -C 1 -w ./dump.pcap`

Comment: Seems like it would be super easy to modify tcpdump to put the number before the .pcap. Maybe even offer it as a pull request to the core maintainers. @guyharris

Answer (score 0):

I figure tcpdumps "postrotate-command" can be used for this.
`tcpdump [...] -z <command>` will call the command after each capture with the current filename, hence I presume you should be able to rename files with it, if you do the renaming in a small shell script:

> -z postrotate-command
>                 Used  in  conjunction  with the -C or -G options, this will make
>                 tcpdump run " postrotate-command file " where file is the  save-
>                 file  being  closed after each rotation. For example, specifying
>                 -z gzip or -z bzip2 will compress each savefile  using  gzip  or
>                 bzip2.